# Change interval of random number generator

Tags: algorithm, random

Given a random number generator `r()` which produces a (pseudo-)random `double` in the interval `[0,1]` with uniform density, ie `p(x) = 1` for `0 <= x <= 1` and `p(x) = 0` elsewhere, create a random number generator `r(a,b)` which generates a `double` in the interval `[a,b]` with density `p(x) = 1/(b-a)` for `a <= x <= b`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating Uniform Random Deviates within a given range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446153/generating-uniform-random-deviates-within-a-given-range)

Comment: The linked question is only considering integers.

Comment: Why the elaborate answers?  Isn't it as simple as `a + (b - a) * r()`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe (and have tested) that this produces a uniform distribution.

```
r(a,b) = ((r * b) mod (b-a)) + a
```

but is there another more obvious way?

Yes:

```
r(a, b) = r*(b-a) + a
```

Comment: It is not correct also. It does not generate numbers in [b-1,b)

Comment: Should it be (... mod (b-a + 1)) ... ?

Comment: It depends on how you define modolus for real numbers as well.